# Weird IP address coming from ping command

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, ping, ip-address

Usually, when I ping a website, I will see the IP address of the domain.

However, recently, I notice that my ping command, instead of showing the IP address of the website, is showing something that looks like a physical address but it isn't my physical address too.

[image]

Not only that, it's only after this has started recently that I notice that my wifi hasn't been stable. My wifi connection keeps showing connected but with that "No internet access" notice.

What is that weird address coming from the ping command and why is this happening? Is this actually the culprit that causes my wifi to keep having that "No internet access" issue?

Comment: That's an IPv6 address.  Not certain about the cause or fix without diving into it.

Comment: That particular IPv6 address isn’t your localhost by the way

Comment: You can just use the `-4` parameter after the ping command before the DNS name you ping so `ping -4 google.com` will force the ping command to use the IPv4 addressing. Run `ping /?` for more detail. Check your router and turn off any DHCP functionality for IPv6 potentially as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The address you are seeing is an IPv6 address instead of an IPv4 address. For some reason your computer is attempting to access the site over IPv6. Normally this will only happen if your computer has a valid IPv6 address and working IPv6 Internet connection. You can verify IPv6 status of your computer by visiting the [IPv6 Test site](http://test-ipv6.com).

Comment: Remember to test that site both when you have working Internet and when you have "No internet access"

Comment: Under what situation should I then use IPv6? I have no idea when it did the switch, but can I just switch back to IPv4?

Comment: And is IPv6 support something by my ISP or my own network card?

Comment: Can you access your router in your browser and look at the internet configuration?

Comment: It is possible to disable IPv6 entirely in the network control panel of your system. Exactly how to do that is really a separate question which you can probably Google fairly easily. However, unless you are having issues where you cannot browse to sites and the Internet is not working there is no reason to disable IPv6. Your computer should automatically use IPv6 for sites that support it and use IPv4 for sites that do not.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to add `-4` at the end of the `ping` command. For example, see the below command.

```
ping raspberrypi.local -4
```

**See the result of a command with -4**

[image]

**See the result of a command without -4**

[image]